# webapi: unittest ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecutingAsync with moq

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, actionfilterattribute

**Edit: [Why doesn't Moq run the overridden ToString method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998611/why-doesnt-moq-run-the-overridden-tostring-method) gives the hint.** I had to set filtermock.CallBase to true. Now it works.

I'm trying to write a unittest for an asp.net webapi project. What I want to do is, to test a function with its corresponding filter. I setup the controller and the filter moq objects like this:

```
var filtermock= new Mock<MyActionFilterAttribute>();
filtermock.SetupGet(attr => attr.UserId).Returns(userName);
[...]
var controllermock = new Mock<MyController>();
var filtermock = new Mock<MyActionFilterAttribute>();
```

The unittest looks like this:

```
var controller = controllermock.Object;
var filter = filtermock.Object;
await filter.OnActionExecutingAsync(null, CancellationToken.None);
await controller.MyTestFunction();
await filter.OnActionExecutedAsync(null, CancellationToken.None);
```

The problem is, that the overridden functions OnActionExecutingAsync and OnActionExecudedAsync are not beeing called when i run/debug the test. I guess the baseclasses of ActionFilterAttribute are called? Could anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect filtermock to ever be called? It does not appear the filtermock is associated to the controllermock so the controllermock is not even aware of the filtermock.

This is the same issue I am trying to resolve myself: how to inject an action filter into a controller.

Comment: i call it directly in the unittest:

`await filter.OnActionExecutingAsync(context, cancellationToken);

await controller.DoSomeStuff();

await filter.OnActionExecutedAsync(context,cancellationToken.None);`